# Php, MySql Sum from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make this query work:

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(SUM(days), 0) AS days 
FROM
  `table_days` 
WHERE task = 1 
GROUP BY task 
UNION
ALL 
SELECT 
  IFNULL(SUM(total), 0) AS total 
FROM
  `table_total` 
WHERE task = 1 
GROUP BY task ;
```

I have two tables :

```
1. table_days

    id      task    days    
    ==========================
    1       1       3.00
    2       1       2.00


2. table_total
    id      task    total   
    ==========================
    1       3       0.00
```

The query above partially works, the result is:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [days] => 5.00
)
```

but I would like to get the result from second table even if there are no records found. Something like

```
stdClass Object
(
    [days] => 5.00
    [total] => 0.00
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work for you (example at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/970a35/3)):

```
SELECT
  IFNULL(SUM(days), 0) AS value, 'days' as name
FROM
  `table_days`
WHERE task = 1
GROUP BY task
UNION ALL

(SELECT CASE WHEN u.value = -1 then 0 else value end as value, 'total' as name
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
          IFNULL(SUM(total), 0) AS value
        FROM
          `table_total`
        WHERE task = 1
        GROUP BY task
        UNION
        SELECT -1 as value
    ) u
);
```

And it will return:

```
+-------+-------+
| value | name  |
+-------+-------+
|     5 | days  |
|     0 | total |
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: task-3 is purposely left there, so if there are no records, I sill want to return 0

Comment: ok, i get it. I fix code and now it works for task=1 in second select

Comment: Still not working. This is what I'm getting:  [value] => 5.000 [name] => days

Answer (score 1):

Try This query

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(SUM(days), 0) AS days 
FROM
  `table_days` 
WHERE task = 1 
GROUP BY task 
UNION
ALL 
SELECT 
  SUM(case when task = 1 then IFNULL(total,0) else 0 end) AS total 
FROM
  `table_total` 
GROUP BY task ;
```

Comment: I tried your query, and produces exactly the same result as mine, (total value is not shown)

Answer (score 0):

The conundrum with your current approach is that the second half of your `UNION` query doesn't "know" anything about the tasks which appear in the first half.
 However, joining the two tables would allow you to leverage the relationship between the two tables.  I think a better way of doing this would be to `LEFT JOIN` the `table_days` table with `table_total`, thereby retaining all tasks:

```
SELECT t1.task, t1.sum_days, t2.sum_total
FROM
(
    SELECT task, IFNULL(SUM(days), 0) AS sum_days
    FROM `table_days`
    GROUP BY task
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT task, IFNULL(SUM(total), 0) AS sum_total
    FROM `table_total`
    GROUP BY task
) t2
    ON t1.task = t2.task
WHERE t1.task = 1
```

If you want to include all tasks from the `table_days` table, you can remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Your query gives 
Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'days' in 'field list'. Please update second select statement IFNULL(SUM(days), 0) with IFNULL(SUM(total), 0)

Comment: @Pallavi Sorry that should have been the `total` column, please try it again.